# PHP Templating Engine

Tags: php

I need help refactoring code for my PHP template engine. I just have this feeling that the code is too disorganized and can be improved performance-wise. My main concerns are running a preg_match on every line in the file and hard-coding functionality for conditional and repeat blocks.

```
<?php

class Template extends Component
{
    private static $actions = array();     // Template actions

    private $data = array();               // Template data
    private $path = null;                  // Path to template file

    private $in_block = false;             // In conditional block
    private $execute_block = false;        // Whether to execute block

    private $repeat_block = false;         // In repeat block
    private $repeat_data = null;           // Repeat data
    private $repeat_start = 0;             // Start of repeat index
    private $repeat_end = 0;               // End of repeat index
    private $repeat_buffer = array();      // Stores repeated code


    // Registers a template action, makign it available to use inside a template
    public static function registerAction($action_name, $function_handler)
    {
        if (!is_callable($function_handler))
            trigger_error(sprintf('Function %s does not exist in Template::registerAction', $function_handler), E_USER_ERROR);

        self::$actions[$action_name] = $function_handler; 
    }


    // Runs a template action and returns the result
    public function executeAction($action, $arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($action, self::$actions))
        {
            // If there is just one argument being passed, then don't pass an array
            if (count($arguments) == 1)
                $arguments = $arguments[0]; 

            return call_user_func_array(self::$actions[$action], array($arguments, $this)); 
        }
    }


    // Initializes the Template component
    public function __construct($path, $data = null)
    {
        $this->path = $path; 

        if (is_array($data))
            $this->data = $data; 
    }


    // Adds or modifies an entry in the template data
    public function set_data($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value; 
    }


    // Returns an entry in the template data
    public function get_data($key)
    {
        return $this->data[$key]; 
    }


    // Returns all template data
    public function all_data()
    {
        return $this->data; 
    }


    // Starts a conditional block
    public function startBlock($execute)
    {
        $this->in_block = true; 
        $this->execute_block = $execute ? true : false;  // Only allow boolean values
    }


    // Starts a repeat block
    public function startRepeatBlock($repeat_data)
    {
        // If data does not exist, then do not execute the block
        if (empty($this->data[$repeat_data]) || count($this->data[$repeat_data]) == 0)
            return; 

        $this->repeat_data = $repeat_data; 
        $this->repeat_block = true; 
        $this->repeat_end = is_array($this->data[$repeat_data][0]) ? count($this->data[$repeat_data]) : 1; 
    }


    // Ends a conditional or repeat block. If latter, then executes all code in repeat buffer. 
    public function endBlock()
    {
        $this->in_block = false; 
        $this->execute_block = false; 

        // If a repeat block ended, then process the entire block
        if ($this->repeat_block)
        {
            $data = $this->data[$this->repeat_data];
            $final = ''; 

            // If there are no arrays in the array, then change it into that form
            if (!is_array($data[0]))
                $data = array($data);


            // Begin processing
            while ($this->repeat_start < $this->repeat_end)
            {
                $entry = $data[$this->repeat_start++]; 

                // Set the appropriate variables
                foreach ($entry as $key => $value)
                {
                    $key = $this->repeat_data . '[' . $key . ']'; 
                    $this->data[$key] = $value;
                }

                // Process the entire block once
                foreach ($this->repeat_buffer as $arr)
                {
                    if (count($arr) == 3)
                    {
                        list($before, $after, $entry) = $arr; 
                        $line = $before . $this->processEntry($entry) . $after; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $line = $arr; 
                    }

                    $final .= $line; 
                }
            }

            // Reset the repeat variables
            $this->repeat_block = false; 
            $this->repeat_data = null; 
            $this->repeat_start = 0; 
            $this->repeat_end = 0; 
            $this->repeat_buffer = array(); 


            // Return the final result result
            return $final; 
        }
    }


    // Returns whether the current line of code is allowed to be executed or not
    public function canExecute()
    {
        return !$this->in_block || ($this->in_block && $this->execute_block);
    }


    // Renders the template, displaying it to the user
    public function render()
    {
        echo $this->content(); 
    }


    // Returns the final, parsed template data
    public function content()
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->path))
            return;

        /* 0 = before, 1 = entry #1, 2 = entry #2, 3 = after */
        $content = file_get_contents($this->path); 
        $pattern = '/^(.*)\<\%\s*(.+)\s*\%\>(.*)$/'; 
        $lines = explode("\n", $content); 
        $javascript = false; 

        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            // Pattern match the line
            preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches); 

            $result = ''; 

            // If there are no matches, then don't parse it and add the raw string to output
            if (count($matches) == 0)
            {
                // Only add if the "block conditions" are correct and repeat mode is off
                if ($this->canExecute() && !$this->repeat_block)
                    $final .= $line; 

                // If repeat block mode is on, then add it to the repeat buffer
                if ($this->repeat_block)
                    $this->repeat_buffer[] = $line; 

                continue; 
            }   


            // Parse the matches and run the appropriate action         
            $before = $matches[1]; 
            $after = $matches[3]; 
            $entry = $matches[2]; 
            $return = ''; 


            // If the entry signals a block end of "end()" then close the block
            if (trim($entry) == "end()")
                $final .= $this->endBlock();


            // Only run the entry if it is in an executable block
            if (!$this->canExecute())
                continue; 


            // If this is a repeating block, then don't process, instead "record" the line
            if ($this->repeat_block)
            {
                $this->repeat_buffer[] = array($before, $after, $entry);
                continue; 
            }

            // Process the entry
            $return = $this->processEntry($entry);

            // Add the processed line to the final result if not empty
            $result = $before . $return . $after; 
            if (!empty($result)) $final .= $result . "\n"; 
        }
        return $final; 
    }


    // Processes a special block 
    public function processEntry($entry)
    {
        // If "()" exists in the entry, then it's a function call
        if (strpos($entry, ')') !== false)
        {
            list($function, $arguments) = explode('(', $entry, 2);
            $arguments = array_map('trim', explode(',', substr($arguments, 0, strlen($arguments) - 2)));
            return $this->executeAction($function, $arguments); 
        }

        // Otherwise, assume it's a variable
        return html($this->data[clean($entry)]); 
    }
}


/* Define some basic template actions */
function TemplateAction_raw($string, $obj)
{
    return html_entity_decode($obj->get_data($string), ENT_QUOTES); 
}

function TemplateAction_multiline($string, $obj)
{
    return nl2br(html($obj->get_data($string))); 
}

function TemplateAction_json($data, $obj)
{
    return json_encode($obj->get_data($data));
}

function TemplateAction_include($location, $obj)
{
    $path = SNIPPETS . $location . '.php'; 
    $template = (new Template($path, $obj->all_data())); 
    return $template->content(); 
}

function TemplateAction_setTitle($title, $obj)
{
    $obj->set_data('page_title', $title);
}

function TemplateAction_title($_, $obj)
{
    $title = $obj->get_data('page_title'); // For some reason I need a separate variable

    if (empty($title))
        return Config::read('HTML.default_title');

    return html(Config::read('HTML.title_prefix') . $obj->get_data('page_title') . Config::read('HTML.title_postfix'));
}

function TemplateAction_flash($_, $obj)
{
    return html($obj->get_data('flash_message'));
}

function TemplateAction_no_flash($_, $obj)
{
    $obj->startBlock(strlen($obj->get_data('flash_message')) == 0);
}

function TemplateAction_iterate($string, $obj)
{
    $obj->startRepeatBlock($string);
}


/* Register template actions */
Template::registerAction('raw', 'TemplateAction_raw'); 
Template::registerAction('multiline', 'TemplateAction_multiline');
Template::registerAction('json', 'TemplateAction_json');
Template::registerAction('include', 'TemplateAction_include'); 
Template::registerAction('setTitle', 'TemplateAction_setTitle');
Template::registerAction('title', 'TemplateAction_title'); 
Template::registerAction('flash', 'TemplateAction_flash'); 


/* Register template blocks */
Template::registerAction('no_flash', 'TemplateAction_no_flash'); 


/* Register the one and only repeat block */
Template::registerAction('iterate', 'TemplateAction_iterate');

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I saw a similar templating engine, and it was so unnecessarily complex that I replaced it with something stupidly simple:

```
function php_as_template( $_t_filename, $_t_vars = null ){
  // make local variables from values in $_t_vars
  if( $_t_vars ) foreach( $_t_vars as $_t_k => &$_t_v)  $$_t_k =&  $_t_v;
  ob_start();
    include $_t_filename;
    $_t_result = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $_t_result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
echo php_as_template('hello.php',array('a'=>'Hello','b'=>array('World!')));
```

`hello.php`:

```
<h1><?php echo $a; ?><?php echo $b[0]; ?></h1>


<?php

function php_as_template( $_t_, $_t_vars = null ){
  // make local variables from values in $_t_vars
  if( $_t_vars ) foreach( $_t_vars as $_t_k => &$_t_v)  $$_t_k =&  $_t_v;
  ob_start();
    $_t_ = '?'.'>'.$_t_;
    $_t_ = preg_replace_callback( '/<\%\s*(.+?)\s*\%\>/', 'pattern_callback', $_t_ );
    echo 'PROCESSED TEMPLATE: '.str_replace( "\n","<br>",htmlspecialchars( $_t_ ));
    eval( $_t_ );
    $_t_result = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $_t_result;
}

function pattern_callback( $matches ){
  global $template_functions;
  $s = $matches[1];
  if( preg_match('/^(\w+)\s*\((.*)\)/', $s, $m )){ // start of function call
    if( array_key_exists( $m[1], $template_functions )){ // function exists
      return '<?php echo call_user_func_array('
      .'$GLOBALS["template_functions"]["'.$m[1].'"], array('.$m[2].')); ?>';
    }
  }
}

$template_functions = array(
//'action name called in template' => anything call_user_func_array accepts
  'json' => array('TemplateActions','json') // static class function
 ,'dump' => 'var_dump' // plain func
);

class TemplateActions {
  static function json( $data ){ return json_encode( $data ); }
}


$a = 'Hello';
$b = array('World!');
$template = '
  <h1> <?php echo $a; ?> <?php echo $b[0]; ?> </h1><br>
  The JSON is:<br>
  <% json( array(1,$a,$b) ) %><br>
  <% dump( array(1,$a,$b) ) %>
';
echo php_as_template( $template ,compact('a','b'));
```

Comment: Yes, that is a very simple template engine. But what if i want more advanced functionality? For example in my engine I have template actions which are basically "functions" that can be called inside of the templates. How would I go about implementing that without making things overly complex?

Comment: See new example, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For a standard (W3C) and complete (with PHP registered functions) *template engine*, see this tutorial for use "XSLT 1.0 + PHP" templating: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions

To build your "every no standard" template engine, a good start point is the "smallest PHP template engine":  https://code.google.com/p/smallest-template-system/wiki/PHP

PS: if you reply comments here, we can extend this answer.